# Pushing to new branch throws 403 error on GitHub

Tags: git, github

I created a branch by doing

git checkout -b branchname

I then created some code, saved it, and then did

git add .
git commit -m "message"

I then tried to do git push -u origin branchname

When I tried to push, it throws this error:

remote: Password authentication is temporarily disabled as part of a brownout. Please use a personal access token instead.
remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-07-30-token-authentication-requirements-for-api-and-git-operations/ for more information.
fatal: unable to access 'reponame': The requested URL returned error: 403

I havent switched back to master yet, but this has never happened until I tried to push to the new branch. Any particular reason this could be happening?

Comment: Having the same problem.

Comment: Click on the link that you embedded in your question. GitHub are phasing out password access entirely, and are temporarily forcing people to use tokens so that they'll notice.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Please try this:

```
 git config --global http.proxy
```

And use your token instead of password, of course.

Comment: Ahh, I have not created a PAT for this speciifc computer. I guess its time to make one then.